# Rockstar Game Launcher and Ownership

Tags: grand-theft-auto-san-andreas, rockstar-games-launcher

Will uninstalling a game from Rockstar's new game launcher void my ownership of that game?

I have claimed the free giveaway version of Grand Theft Auto: San Andreas, like many others did, but now I want to uninstall that game. Will I be able to install it again later, linked to the same Social Club account?

Comment: It is the same as any other game library/store out there, once bought they stay in your library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No worries, **once claimed, it will be tied to your account**: it's a free game, not a trial version.

For verification, this image was pulled from the official Rockstar Games [article](https://www.rockstargames.com/newswire/article/61123/Download-The-Rockstar-Games-Launcher?utm_source=twitter&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=rockstargamelauncher-09172019&utm_content=newswire) announcing the giveaway as part of the release of their official game launcher - mentioning a "*FREE*" copy:

[image: Rockstar announcement]

The launcher works as any other (Steam, Epic Launcher, Uplay, GOG Galaxy), in that you can install and uninstall games whenever you feel like it.